# How to hide config/template files in npm package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm developing my web application template (ReactJS for example) and I wanted to put the configuration files (webpack, ts-lint) and template files ("public/index.html") into my npm package that I'm going to publish. How can this be implemented?